# Best practice for syncing Core Data database with images to Dropbox via ParcelKit

Tags: ios, core-data, dropbox

I have an iOS app that uses Core Data and ParcelKit to sync with Dropbox. However, the Dropbox Datastore API only allows records of 100K so it will not sync images that I store in the database. Any other workaround than storing images as separate files with filenames stored in the base? It is a little fragile when user can alter the content of the imagefile-folder thus braking the link to the database.

Answer (score 2):

You should not store large images in the Core Data persistent store. Apple recommends that you should only store small images, such as thumbnails, perhaps 20K max. If you go beyond that, performance will eventually degrade significantly.

Thus, you cannot really avoid storing the images in separate files and storing their name/location in Core Data. This is the recommended pattern.

I do not see why you think this is *fragile*. Presumably you will store the images in the app sandbox there is no way the user can fiddle with them unless the iPhone is jailbroken.

The Dropbox sync should be managed independently from this setup.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm quite new to iOS development so I wasn't aware of that recommendation by Apple. With "fragile" I meant that for syncing using Dropbox I have to store them in a Dropbox folder where the user have access and can mess things up. Storing in the App sandbox is of course safe enough.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Dropbox just killed the Datastore API and will take it off line in 2016. :-(

You should monitor this ParcelKit Issue:

> **Dropbox Datastore is Deprecated #34**
>   https://github.com/overcommitted/ParcelKit/issues/34

Comment: Thanks - I just noticed too. Very sad as the Datastore API is quite good. Except for the 100K record size limit, that is.